# Telebot: replying to user with the same message

Tags: python, py-telegram-bot-api, telebot

I am making a translator bot with inline button using Telebot. When user sends message the bot will offer him to choose a language. And when user has chosen a language, bot should translate it.

What should I write to `text` variable in the code below?

How can I describe the user message/input?

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
from googletrans import Translator 
BOT_TOKEN = "<Bot_Token>"
bot = telebot.TeleBot(BOT_TOKEN)

key =types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
btn1=types.InlineKeyboardButton(text ="Amharic" , callback_data="am")
btn2=types.InlineKeyboardButton(text =" Arabic" , callback_data="ar")
btn3=types.InlineKeyboardButton(text =" Hindi" , callback_data="hi")
key.add(btn1,btn2,btn3)
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call:True)
def callback(call):
    #here is my question, what does i have to write in text variable ?
    text= call.message.chat.text
     #?????????
    if call.data=="am":
        translator=Translator()
        translation=translator.translate(text,dest="am")
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id,text)
        
@bot.message_handler(commands = ["start"])
def welcome (message):
  bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'HELLO!!! send a message!')
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda call:True)
def choose(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"select your language:",reply_markup=key)
bot.infinity_polling()
```